# phpmyadmin “Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.”

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to modify the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` in order to allow remote users (not only localhost) to login

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

When I get into phpmyadmin webpage, I am not prompted for user and password, before getting the error message: `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server`.
My system is Fedora 20

Comment: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22184 Re: You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.
Postby maibamsharat » 2016/09/19 19:34:04 If you've done all that permission settings, then try simple things like putting the url with index.php (like, http://your-address/phpmyadmin/index.php)...sometime the default landing page index.php is not detected by your webserver if the setting is not done correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your httpd error log see if it has more specific info about the denial: /var/log/httpd/error_log

Also, if selinux is enforcing then try turning it off for testing:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
$ getenforce
```

Have a look at your perms on /usr/share/phpMyAdmin as compared to /var/www/html

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html
```

There's always the d'oh! check too...did you actually restart/reload the webserver after adding that config?

```
$ apachectl restart
```

Comment: `/var/log/httpd/error_log` says:
`[Thu May 29 08:55:36.517399 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1168] [client removed_ip] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin`

`# ls -ld /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html` says
`drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 16 mag 22.21 /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 17 apr 20.32 /var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

Add `Allow from 10.10.10.10` (replace `10.10.10.10` w/ your IP address), don't forget to restart apache `service httpd restart`). feel free to take a look at mine I uploaded it for you to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hvU3SGs1 (line 24, 42).

Comment: Allowing a single IP address is quite useless

Comment: @Caterpillar some might call it "security", but you can replace it with a range of IPs or you don't need that "security" take the whole block (Order,Allow,Deny) out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file: `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` and replace yours with following:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache: `service httpd restart`

(phpMyAdmin v4.0.10.8)

Answer (score 0):

this is my phpmyadmyn.comf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    <IfDefine APACHE24>
       Require all granted
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine !APACHE24>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
 php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
 php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
 php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
 php_admin_value max_input_time 360
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you have already configured `.htaccess` file for authentication to work. You should post it's content too.

You need to have it under `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin` directory and can contain something similar:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.phpmyadmin.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Aditionally you also need have the line `DirectoryIndex index.php` in you directory block.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        [...]
```

You only need to customize your `<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">`part and the .htaccess file. The rest you can keep as it is for security.

See a detailed how-to here: [How To Install and Secure phpMyAdmin with Apache on a CentOS 7 Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server)